# C# passing objects to different methods

Tags: c#, .net

I have a quick question. I have an object that I am trying to pass to a different method in a different class.

```
 public virtual void Geocode(ICustomer customer)
    {
        RouteObjects.Customer roCustomer = customer as RouteObjects.Customer;

        if (customer != null)
        {
            RouteObjectsRepository.Geocode(roCustomer);
            GeoCodeUpdateEventPublisher.UpdateGeoCustomer(roCustomer);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to pass the roCustomer object to GeoCodueUpdateEventPublisher in method updategeocustomer. my updateGeoCustomer looks like this

```
 public virtual void UpdateGeoCustomer(object roCustomer)
    {
        Publish(roCustomer); 
    }
```

I wanted to know if this is the proper way to pass this object? I am then going to call method publish and it will look something like this.

```
 protected virtual void Publish(object roCustomer)
    {

            PublishMessage publishMessage = CreatePublishMessage(roCustomer);

            if (publishMessage != null)
            {
                Subscribers.AsParallel().ForAll(s => s.Send(publishMessage));
            }

    }
```

I am just trying to verify if I am passing this object around correctly

Comment: What does "passing it correctly" mean? Does your code work - thats the primary means of discovering if something is correct

Comment: Your code is fine. The 'correctness' is determined by your intention, i.e. do you want Publish to accept any object or actually objects that implement your ICustomer interface. etc. If so, then you should retain your interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently "wrong" with passing it around as an "object" rather than the type that it is or that ICustomer interface, it really depends on the specific use case and coding style. If you need to access properties on it and you pass it around as object you'd need to cast it and then that'd be an unnecessary and bad way to go about things (i.e., if you pass it as "object" to that Update method and then it goes (MyObjectType)obj.Whatever = "Something"; then you're doing something questionable).

Comment: So after the program does its GeoCode stuff what I am wanting to do is take that roCustomer object and pass it to my update to kick off a message queue so another program will pick it up. I do only want certain things out of the objectl ike customer tracking number x, y, cooridinates. things like that.

Comment: From that explanation, you should pass it as the type that it actually is up until the point where it gets sent to your message queue, at which point you should send the values from the object that are to be tracked.

Comment: RouteObjects.Customer is a class so I am passing this around correctly when i get to the method to put the items within the object into the queue I do roCustomer. and I dont get to access the items within the objects. Sorry I just may not be understanding correctly

Comment: Instead of having (object roCustomer) as the parameters for your function, you want (RouteObjects.Customer roCustomer), and then you have access. It was unclear what you were asking if that was your question all along.

Comment: yes that fixed everything thank you sorry I didn't ask the right question

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it is to declare the receiving function using the correct type. UNLESS your function needs to work on a parameter of *ANY* type.

Comment: Good way of putting it - to expand on his wording, basically to be "correct" you want to be as specific as possible and only loosen the type to something more generic if the function is meant to handle something more generic.